# Do semiconductors exist at very high temperatures (1000-2000 °C)?

Tags: temperature, material-science, semiconductor-physics

Regular (such as silicon) semiconductors stop being a semiconductor and become conductive at somewhere above 100°C. Some wide bandgap semiconductors stay semiconductive for temperatures up to around 600°C. I would think that at higher temperatures materials with a larger band gap stay semiconductive, but I haven't been able to verify that. Do semiconductors exist at higher temperatures such as 1000 to 2000 °C or higher?

*edit:* I'm not aware of a definition that makes a sharp distinction between insulators and semiconductors. If it makes a difference, I'm interested in 'semiconductorness' in the sense that it should in principle be possible to make a transistor out of the material.

Comment: There may well be a temperature at which glass can be classed as a semiconductor?  [Conductivity of glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBnICnUhTZI) and note how the glass becomes self heating because of the current passing through it.

Comment: Remember that TI has some IC for oil drilling working at 2000 degree, but can't find any information online now....

Comment: @Farcher The conductance of glass is I think caused by ions starting to flow when the glass starts to melt. I don't know if that classifies as semiconductance, but I doubt it. Salt water (which is also an ionic conductor) has a conductivity in the same range as semiconductors, but isn't usually counted as such.

Comment: You definitely can't use silicon at those temperatures, but some other semiconductors may work. You may be interested in this paper on InAlN/GaN at 1000C (and later followup work) https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6213492